# Multithreading violation all that is left to us is honor (fails)

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I've been banging my head 2 days now with this blaming on the developers and myself. So I went to try to simplify the sample and try to understand this flag:

1. I created a core data project from the wizard (master detail app)
2. Added the flag to the arguments: `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1`
3. Added simple code in the viewDidLoad method:

   ```
   NSFetchRequest *fr = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
   _events = [self.pc.viewContext executeFetchRequest:fr error:nil];
   Event *event = _events.firstObject;

   NSOperationQueue *opQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
   NSManagedObjectID *objID = [event objectID];
   [opQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
       NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.pc.newBackgroundContext;
       Event *bgEvent = [context objectWithID:objID]; // Thread 5: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
   }];
   ```
4. Ran the app and got this crash (check comment 1 line before last)

So, I'm trying to move a main MOC object to a background MOC and it crashes.

Am I missing something when passing objects between MOCs in different threads?

NOTE: `pc` is just the persistentContainer created by the wizard and stored in this controller `strong` property. And yes, it has stores and a proper URL, all is good that if I remove this piece of code the app won't crash. I added this code after I added some rows to the `Event` entity, so I can fetch objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't operate on an NSManagedObjectContext on an arbitrary queue. You need to use the context's queue. That means wrapping your call to `objectWithID:` in either `context.perform()` (async) or `context.performAndWait()` (sync).

Generally speaking, you should use the context's queue instead of creating your own `NSOperationQueue`, but if you need your own queue for some reason, that's fine; you just still have to use the context's queue for the context's operations.

See [Core Data Programming Guide: Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH24-SW1) for full details.

---

From your comments, you've written the following:

```
NSManagedObjectID *objID = [event objectID];
[self.pc.viewContext performBlockAndWait:^{ 
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.pc.newBackgroundContext;
   Event *bgEvent = [context objectWithID:objID]; 
}];
```

That's incorrect, and the cause of your problem. You can't use `context` inside the queue of `viewContext`. What I believe you mean here is:

```
NSManagedObjectID *objID = [event objectID];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.pc.newBackgroundContext
[context performBlock:^{
    Event *bgEvent = [context objectWithID:objID]; 
    ....
}];
```

You need to use `context` within its own `perform block`, not some other context's `perform` block.

It wouldn't make sense to use `performBlockAndWait` here since that would block the main queue. Instead, this will asynchronously perform this block on a background queue, which I believe is what you're trying to do.

Comment: Wrapping it in the `context.perform()` or `context.performAndWait()` didn't work, but it did wrapping it in `persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask`. What I wanted to do is the `performAndWait` and `performBackgroundTask` is not acceptable for what I intend to do. Documentation doesn't say you can't use `performAndWait` on a background context or that you can't create your own `NSOperationQueue`. NSPersistentContainer inits its `viewContext` to be `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, aka I can use `context.performAndWait()` but launch arg makes app to crash.

Comment: How did you wrap it in `context.perform()`? Did you put it inside the `addOperationWithBlock` (or remove the `addOperationWithBlock`)? Or did you put it outside the `addOperationWithBlock` (which would not work)? I don't understand what you mean by "is not acceptable." I don't know what you mean by "you can't use performAndWait on a background context." You absolutely can do that (and must). I don't know what `newBackgroundContext` is returning (how is that context configured)? You're correct that `viewContext` is on the main queue, but that's not the context you should use for background work

Comment: I removed `addOperationWithBlock` all together just to prove app crashes the same (when launch arg is ON). I replaced the block part with the following code `[self.pc.viewContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.pc.newBackgroundContext;
        Event *bgEvent = [context objectWithID:objID];
    }];`. And no, I'm not using `viewContext` in a thread other than main, When running in a bg thread, I always use the `newBackgroundContext` that's configured for use in a background thread.

Comment: Yes, just after I posted my comment and changed the code and found that same issue in my code. I'm marking yours as he answer.